# Hosting bot at telegram with Azure using Node.js

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework

Trying to host my telegram bot with Azure?
Not sure how to proceed

Used Node.js to code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the [Deploy a bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/deploy-bot-overview) documentation topic. There you will find the details on how to proceed to deploy to azure.